# Hide the text field before select from menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create a drop down for dependency select menu.  As how it works in jsfiddle.

```js
$('#user_time_zone').on('change', function() {
dateCalender = $(this).val();
if (dateCalender == 'Single Date') {
        $('#sd').show();
      $('#rd').hide();

}

 if (dateCalender == 'Range of Dates') {
    $('#rd').show();    
            $('#sd').hide();       
}  
});
```

```html
   

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id = "user_time_zone">
            <option>Type </option>
            <option value = "Single Date">Single Date</option>
            <option value = "Range of Dates">Range of Dates</option>
        </select>
        <div id='sd'>Single Date:<input type="text" id="singleDate" name="singleDate" /></div>
        <div id='rd'>Range of Dates:<input type="text" id="rangeDates" name="rangeDates" /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BeePositive/sg5db90t/1/)

I wondering can I hide the input textfield before selection. And only show as the created jquery in jsfiddle.

Comment: Use JavaScript to add `CSS` class $('The tag selector can be a class').hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add an initial state in the JS and create another condition for type, just as the updated jsfiddle

```
$('#user_time_zone').on('change', function() {
 dateCalender = $(this).val();
  if (dateCalender == 'Single Date') {
    $('#sd').show();
    $('#rd').hide();

  } else if (dateCalender == 'Range of Dates') {
    $('#rd').show();    
    $('#sd').hide();       
  } else if (dateCalender == 'Type') {
    $('#rd').hide();    
    $('#sd').hide();       
  }
});


$('#rd').hide();    
$('#sd').hide();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v5zqsxtf/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class and initially add it to the `div`. Now on change of the `select` you can `addClass` and `removeClass` to show or hide the input

```js
$('#user_time_zone').on('change', function() {
  dateCalender = $(this).val();
  if (dateCalender === 'Single Date') {
    $('#sd').removeClass('outputField');
    $('#rd').addClass('outputField');
  }

  if (dateCalender === 'Range of Dates') {
    $('#sd').addClass('outputField');
    $('#rd').removeClass('outputField');
  }
});
```

```css
.outputField {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="user_time_zone">
  <option>Type </option>
  <option value="Single Date">Single Date</option>
  <option value="Range of Dates">Range of Dates</option>
</select>

<div id='sd' class='outputField'>Single Date:<input type="text" id="singleDate" name="singleDate" /></div>
<div id='rd' class='outputField'>Range of Dates:<input type="text" id="rangeDates" name="rangeDates" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide the elements when the page loads. Then you can add a final `else` statement to the `if` condition in the `change` handler to hide them both if the default option is selected again:

```js
var $rd = $('#rd'), 
  $sd = $('#sd');

$('#user_time_zone').on('change', function() {
  dateCalender = $(this).val();

  if (dateCalender == 'Single Date') {
    $sd.show();
    $rd.hide();
  } else if (dateCalender == 'Range of Dates') {
    $rd.show();
    $sd.hide();
  } else {
    $rd.add($sd).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#sd, #rd { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="user_time_zone">
  <option>Type </option>
  <option value="Single Date">Single Date</option>
  <option value="Range of Dates">Range of Dates</option>
</select><br><br>
<div id="sd">
  Single Date: <input type="text" id="singleDate" name="singleDate" />
</div><br>
<div id="rd">
  Range of Dates: <input type="text" id="rangeDates" name="rangeDates" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want input fields only after selection from drop down rather then using hide/show u can append whole input section after the dropdown option is selected

```
$('#user_time_zone').on('change', function() {

dateCalender = $(this).val();

if (dateCalender == 'Single Date') {

$('#sd').html('Single Date:<input type="text" id="singleDate" name="singleDate" />');


}else{
$('#sd').html('Range of Dates:<input type="text" id="rangeDates" name="rangeDates" />');

}
```

and u will only need

```
<div id='sd'></div>
```

in html part

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case (having only two target elements) you could simply use a `.hide` class and jQuery's `.toggle()` method:

```js
$('#user_time_zone').on('change', () => $('.utz').toggle());
```

```css
.none { display: none; }
```

```html
<select id="user_time_zone">
  <option selected>Single Date</option>
  <option>Range of Dates</option>
</select>
<label class="utz">Single:<input type="text" name="singleDate"></label>
<label class="utz none">Range:<input type="text" name="rangeDates"></label>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```